# How to go to next part in Masked Input mask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

Let's say I have a mask for a text box as: `aa?a-999?999`

the first 2 characters are required but the third one is optional. When a user enters the first two character, does does he jump to the second part to enter the numbers?

I tried tab but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If maskedinput find one `?` in your mask, then everything after it will be considered optional.

[jQuery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) is a little bit more flexible in optional parts of the mask, you're probably going to achieve what you want with it.